# Angular event.target.blur() not working for mobile

Tags: android, html, ios, angular, blur

I have the following code to prevent the buttons to stay focused after they are clicked. It works perfectly for desktop but it doesn't work at all when testing on mobile devices (Both iOS & Android), I'm not sure if I'm missing something here (I already tried replacing *click* with *touchstart* and *touchend*).

```
this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (event) => {
          if (event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
            event.target.blur();
          } else if (event.target.parentNode.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
            event.target.parentNode.blur();
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, in case anyone ever comes across this situation:
It WAS actually working, but on mobile devices an "emulated" *hover* is also applied after pressing buttons, so what I was seeing was the *hover* state, not the *focus* one.

I fixed it by wrapping the hover style of my button inside this block, to make sure that the device supports ACTUAL hover (e.g. using a mouse):

```
  @media (hover: hover) {
    your-element:hover {
      //hover style
    }
  }
```